Accessing a CoreStorage Volume macOS Says it Cannot Mount
I have an external drive I haven't accessed recently (a year ago? Perhaps longer? Certainly within the last three years). This is a bare 3.0 TB Western Digital drive (HDD/platters) I put into a Wavlink USB 3.0 HDD Docking station. The drive spins up and seems OK (no clicking or other sounds like the arm is having trouble accessing blocks). I get a message from macOS that this drive is unreadable.
Looking at it from within Disk Utility I see the name of the drive, its size and that it is a CoreStorage Logical Volume • Mac OS Extended (Encrypted). I have accessed it in the past from my MacBook but thought perhaps since I have upgraded it to Sequoia that the newer OS doesn't read the older formatting.
I have an older iMac running macOS Ventura 13.7.1 which I thought would have no problem reading it if the issue is Sequoia. The iMac did recognize it is an encrypted volume and accepted the password to decrypt the volume. But again I get the message the drive is unreadable and won't mount.
Has this drive become corrupted due to non-use? Or has the older formatting scheme of plastered drives become obsolete with the macOS? I used to do drive recovery decades ago but my skills are outdated and I don't even know what recovery software is currently used (anyone remember when Norton worked on a Mac?)

A newer version of macOS can read all versions of the Apple created file systems. I've read old System 6 floppy disks on new versions of macOS. So that is not it. It is possible that something happened to the drive, but how and when, there is no real way to determine. If it is an HFS+ formatted drive DiskWarrior might be able to recover it, but they have never released a version that works on APFS formatted volumes.

Sadly enough I think your drive is "dead"! How old is that drive?
